# sql query not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ive got a table containing results for a certain sport competition from 2009 - present.
The table contains numerous columns such as hometeam, awayteam, homescore, awayscore etc. As you can see from the image below:

[image]

If I want to display results for a certain team (in this example team Sharks) **for both home and away matches** I do it like so:

```
    SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `hometeam` = 'Sharks' || `awayteam` = 'Sharks'
```

The above code is working fine and I get the correct results as you can see from the image:

[image]

***The problem***

The problem im having is when I want to display BOTH home and away match results for only two SPECIFIC teams, im not getting the correct results. (In the query below im trying to only display home and away results when team Stormers played against team Sharks)
I query the table as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `hometeam` = 'Stormers' || `awayteam` = 'Stormers' && `hometeam` = 'Sharks' || `awayteam` = 'Sharks'
```

You can see from the image below that the above query is returning the wrong results. The query is returning results for both team Stormers and team Sharks for ALL their home and away matches against ALL opponents

[image]

***The question***

Im looking for a way where the query will **only return results for specific teams when they played against each other home and away.** Example: for this query I only wanted to display all results for team Stormers against team Sharks, ignoring all other opponents.

If anyone can be so kind to point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looks like you just have wrong logic. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE (`hometeam` = 'Stormers' AND `awayteam` = 'Sharks')
OR (`hometeam` = 'Sharks' AND `awayteam` = 'Stormers')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Running the above query I get the following message: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). Yet I know for a fact there are fixtures when both those teams played against each other both home and away

Comment: @woz, there's a small typo in you WHERE clause, you're looking for Stormers playing against themselves, or Sharks playing against themselves... if you change it to `WHERE (\`hometeam\` = 'Stormers' AND \`awayteam\` = 'Sharks') OR (\`hometeam\` = 'Sharks' AND \`awayteam\` = 'Stormers')`, then you should get the correct results

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `hometeam` IN ('Stormers', 'Sharks')
AND `awayteam` IN ('Stormers', 'Sharks')
```

This should only return matches where those two teams played against each other.

Comment: Sure thing, I also commented on woz's answer if you prefer to use the OR logic.